# Stop Service from PendingIntent after Notifcation is opened

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want the service to perform a stopForeground and a stopSelf after the notification is clicked followed by the running of pendingIntent.

I have tried using a BroadcastReceiver which is never called as I checked during debugging. I have added it to manifest as well.

```
Intent intentHide = new Intent(this, StopServiceReceiver.class);
PendingIntent hide = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intentHide, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Added it to the builder

```
builder.setContentIntent(hide);
```

And the Broadcast Rec is done separately -

```
public class StopServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 333;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, TimerService.class);
        context.stopService(service);
    }
}
```

Manifest -

```
<receiver
        android:name=".StopServiceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

This is not working. The notification and the service both are alive.

Questions - Should I use addContent instead of setContentIntent ? If yes, then what should the parameters be ? 
Is there anything I went wrong with? What could possibly be wrong with such kind of implementation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the notification.

This code is working perfectly.

```
void creatnotifiaction()
{
    public static final String STOP = "com.example.android";
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 333;

        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(STOP);

        Intent intentHide = new Intent(STOP);
        PendingIntent hide = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,REQUEST_CODE,intentHide,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

     registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

}
```

There no need to separate broadcast receiver use in same class.

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("notification", "Received intent with action " + action);

            switch (action) {
                case STOP:
                    //your code to stop notifications or service. 

                    break;
         }
});
```

Let me know if that work for you.
Thanks...Happy coding.